# Matlab code runs in the command window but not in the script file

Tags: matlab

I have a very simple code in MATLAB for a laser device which I need to use.
Here's the code:

```
% creating a serial port object
s = serial('COM3');

% opening the port
fopen(s);

% enabling the port
fprintf(s, 'e');

% sending the power to the laser
fprintf(s, 'a738.8889');

% disabling the port
fprintf(s, 'd');
fprintf(s, 'z');

fclose(s);
delete(s);
```

The code works perfectly fine when I write them one by one from the command window, but it's not working when I put the whole code in either a script file or a function file.

I don't get any errors or any other messages from MATLAB when I run the script or the function. Any ideas why?

Thank you.

Comment: There shouldn't be any output except for the data on COM3. Do you see that output?

Comment: Maybe it needs some delays for the port to be ready. Executing line by line gives a lot of time between instructions for the port to get ready but executing in sequence might be too fast.

Comment: @Suever well the laser is visible, so if it works I should be able to see the laser (which I can't)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki so you suggest I put a `pause(3)` before writing to the port?

Comment: Ideally if your device needs some processing time, it should return some ready status to accept new instructions. But you can start trying to put a pause(3) in your code and see if it works, yes.

Comment: There is also a possibility, that laser is turned on and immediately turned off (when you run it as a script). Do the commands `fprintf(s, 'd');` and `fprintf(s, 'z');` turn the laser off? I suggest you add `pause(3)` after every command (in case adding it before writing to the port doesn't work).

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I tried delaying the commands and it actually worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried delaying the commands and the script works now. Apparently when the commands are being executed in the script, it is too fast for the device to read them all and that is why it wasn't working.

Comment: Actually @Rotem suggestion also makes a lot of sense. If the commands fprintf(s, 'd'); and fprintf(s, 'z'); turn off the laser, or if the laser is automatically turned off when the port is closed, then your code was maybe working but just for very short time.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki yes, I actually thought of that as well but then I tried the code without the last commands and it didn't work again